# Rest Endpoint to get data from sharepoint catalog

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, catalog

I am able to get data from sharepoint list using this endpoint. But i want to know the endpoint to get data from sharepoint catalog.

Actual URL List: `https://siteurl/sites/Lists/Tracker/AllItems.aspx`

End Point List: `https://siteurl/sites/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tracker')/Items?$top=500`

Actual Catalog URL: `https://siteurl/sites/_catalogs/users/simple.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

The catalogs are still lists, so you can still reach them by `/lists/getbytitle()`.  But you do have to know the "title", which may not be what is in the URL.

For instance the URL to the Composed Looks catalog is:

```
https://server-url/sites/mysite/_catalogs/design/AllItems.aspx
```

But the "title" of that list is actually "Composed Looks", not "design", so you can reach it through the endpoint:

```
https://server-url/sites/mysite/_api/lists/getbytitle('Composed Looks')/items
```

Edit to add: just did a quick check, in your example you used the User Information List (`/_catalogs/users`).  The title of that list is "User Information List", so it can be reached at the endpoint

```
https://server-url/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('User Information List')/items
```

**however**, if what you want to do is work with user data, I would highly recommend using an endpoint *designed* to work with user data like

```
https://server-url/sites/mysite/_api/web/siteusers
```

rather than trying to manipulate the User Information list directly.